# onActivityResult() is not calling in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-camera, onactivityresult

I want to scan QR Code in fragment.

But onActivityResult is not calling.

**Fragment.java**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater ,ViewGroup container ,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_offer ,container ,false );

        scanOffer = view.findViewById( R.id.scanOffer );

        scanOffer.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                scanBarcode();
            }
        } );

        return view;
    }

public void scanBarcode() {
        /** This method will listen the button clicked passed form the fragment **/
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),CaptureActivity.class);
            intent.setAction("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", false);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }


@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                uniqueCode = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                Log.d(TAG, "contents: " + uniqueCode);
                Toast.makeText( getContext() ,uniqueCode ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
//                callAddStoreContestParticipantService();
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "RESULT_CANCELED");
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me.

**onActivityResult()** is not calling

**CaptureActivity.class**  opens Qr after scanning onActivityResult() is not calling

Comment: _CaptureActivity_ is your activity?

Comment: No its not my activity. I use  implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'  for sacnning QR Code..

Comment: `com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar` is for qr code scanning ?

Comment: Please confirm that getting callback in your fragment's activity onActivityResult() method and track the response so that you will be assured that coming into Activity's callback but not in Fragment's call.

Comment: @UnnatiPatadia please try my solution

Comment: Make sure you have used `setResult(0)` from `CaptureActivity` in order to get the result on `Fragment.java`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to call  `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);`
in your fragment
and in your activity you in `onActivityResultMethod()` you have to call `yourfragmnt.onActivityResult()`

Comment: No need to do this.

Comment: As mentioned you need to call getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 0); is correct but later is not needed. Rather this can be a work around to call the onActivityResult() of fragment.

Comment: `yourfragmnt.onActivityResult()` is incorrect way(It's tightly coupled & not utilizing the purpose of `startActivityForResult()`) instead you just have to use `setResult()` https://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example for complete example

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for barcode scan and also override on activity result in parent activity

```
    private static final int BARCODE_REQUEST = 312;
private void startBarcode() {
    //IntentIntegrator.forFragment(getActivity().initiateScan()); // `this` is the current Fragment

    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity()) {
        @Override
        protected void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int code) {
          Fragment.this.startActivityForResult(intent, BARCODE_REQUEST); // REQUEST_CODE override
        }
    };
    //IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
    //IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setPrompt("Scan a barcode");
    integrator.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device
    integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
    integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
    integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
    integrator.setTimeout(15000);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}

   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {

        case BARCODE_REQUEST:
            IntentResult Result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE, resultCode, data);
            if (Result != null) {
                if (Result.getContents() == null) {
                    Timber.i("cancelled scan");
                    showSnackbar("cancelled scan", true);

                } else {
                    Timber.i("Scanned");
                    showSnackbar("Code scan successfully", false);


                    try {


        long id = Long.parseLong(Result.getContents());
//                            getFood(id);

                            searchBarcode(Result.getContents());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


//                    searchBarcode(Result.getContents());
                        //getFood(Long.valueOf(mItem.get(position - 1).getID()));
                    }
                } else {
                    showSnackbar("Barcode not scanned", true);
                    Timber.i("Barcode Result is NULL");
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
                break;
        }

    }
```

You can get reference from this example:[Barcode Scanner](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/08/android-barcode-scanner-using-google-mobile-vision-building-movie-tickets-app/)